# How to incorporate the two loops diagrams in Renormalization Group flow

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

Usually in the text such as Altland and Simon, only one loop RG is discussed. Let's say in some systems where the one loop diagrams vanish, how would we consider the two loops diagrams in the RG procedure?

The problem is that in the RG procedure, we usually calculate the $\beta$ function as (first) derivative of $\ln b$, where $b=\Lambda_0/\Lambda$ is the ratio between the bare and new cutoffs, and then set $b\rightarrow 1$. However, in the two loop diagrams, the momentum integral is $\propto(b-1)^2$. The first derivative of the two loop diagrams gives a result that is $\propto(b-1)$, and setting $b\rightarrow 1$ makes this contribution from the two loop diagrams disappear from the $\beta$ function. So is the RG procedure limited to only one loop diagram? What should we do if the one loop diagrams do not contribute?